# How to get the square brackets that are involved in integration working

Tags: brackets

The clearest way to clearly show what I want is using an example:

[image: Integration]

I am looking for the Latex syntax that gives me the stuff on the right-hand side of the equation.

Comment: What did you type for the left-hand side?  It's the same thing. :-)

Comment: @MatthewLeingang is it? I typed something like \displaystyle\int^4_0 2x+1\ dx. I couldn't find any information on this when searching for "square brackets integration latex"

Comment: I assumed you were asking about the limits of evaluation on the right-hand side.  They are  typed the same way as the limits of integration on the left-hand side...with `^` and `_`.  Sorry for being glib.  But since the right hand side doesn't have any integration, you could [google "square brackets latex"](https://www.google.com/search?q=square+brackets+latex&oq=square+&aqs=chrome.1.57j59j5j0j60j61.2345j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and find the answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
\left[\frac{x^3}{3}+x\right]_1^2
```

Comment: Funnily enough, as I was unsuccessfully searching for how to do this on Google - your name came up in a citation for your name in 1999 came up on some pdf. Thanks :- )

Comment: @nebffa probably because David Carlisle is one of the best contributors in the LaTeX world!

Comment: It works but the square brackets aren't tall enough. They should be the same height as the integral symbol itself.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist better to ask a new question than leave a comment on a years old one, but your comment seems strange actually. The integral sign is a fixed size character, but the `\left[` used here will grow to cover the fraction in its content, so the exact sizes depend on the fonts being used but in general the `[]` will be larger than the integral as they grow arbitrarily large and the integral is fixed size.

Comment: @StandwithGaza as David points out do not forget `\left` and `\right` to have the square brackets look good.